# Select control created in React does not reset on browser refresh (IE11 and Edge)

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have a very simple React application with just one select control. See working application [here](http://www.webpackbin.com/4JyNOWVpW). The select control has 3 values: Sunday, Monday and Tuesday. Sunday is the default value. Unfortunately on IE11 and Microsoft Edge, the select control gets stuck on the selected value even after a browser refresh! For example, select Tuesday and then refresh the browser - the select box does not return to Sunday, it gets stuck on Tuesday! On Chrome and Safari, I don't see this issue. (Note: You will have to download and run the app on various browsers.)

The code for the main component is shown below. Any idea why IE and Edge are misbehaving?

```
import React from 'react';

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedOption: 'sun'
    }
  }

  render() {
    let options = [
      { value: 'sun', label: 'Sunday'  },
      { value: 'mon', label: 'Monday'  },
      { value: 'tue', label: 'Tuesday' }
    ];

    return (
      <select
        className="form-control"
        value={this.state.selectedOption}
        onChange={ e => this.setState({selectedOption: e.target.value}) }>
        {
          options.map(option => {
            return <option value={option.value} key={option.value}>{option.label}</option>;
          })
        }
      </select>
    );
  }

}

export default HelloWorld;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naresh, your code is fine.

Internet Explorer and Edge are misbehaving because they are **caching the select tag**. On Windows, hit the Ctrl+F5 shortcut to hard refresh. On Mac, hold down ⌘ Cmd and ⇧ Shift key and then press R.

Comment: Yep, Ctrl+F5 resets the select box correctly. This is unfortunate though. We have a mission critical application and this IE misbehavior would send the wrong request to the server, with bad consequences :-(

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> If you want to initialize the component with a non-empty value, you can supply a defaultValue prop. For example:

```
  render: function() {
    return <input type="text" defaultValue="Hello!" />;
  }
```

Likewise, `<input type="checkbox">` and `<input type="radio">` support `defaultChecked`, and `<select>` supports `defaultValue`.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#default-value

Comment: the reference you have provided is for uncontrolled components. I am interested in a controlled component and would like to control its value using the value property.