# Controlled Inputs not being clear on page refresh (Microsoft Edge)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-edge

I have a ReactJS application, and have created a controlled component using a simple  html tag.

The issue is when doing refresh on the page in microsoft edge from the refresh button or pressing F5 (when doing enter from the navbar it works fine) the input values are not being clear properly, they get stuck. If I start typing in any input of my form, then they go away.

Evidence: https://www.screencast.com/t/kJupEbHykZ1X

I've already tried:  
 
- clearing the values on *windows.onload* 
- setting *autocomplete='off'* on the input tag  
- creating timeout functions.

To test I added *console.logs* everywhere to be sure all the lifecycle methods are called and that the state in each one of them is empty, and it is.

I've also run into this post: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/21174802/

But none of that seem to fixed the issue.

```
<input
  id={`input-${id}`}
  key={`input-${id}`}
  type={inputType}
  value={value}
  autoComplete="off"
  onChange={this.handleValueChange}
/>
```

Comment: did u update the state or set state to empty on component initial load?

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya yes I did, I added some logs to test it and the state is empty. Works fine in any other browser.

Comment: Maybe setting the `value` in the constructor to be an ampty string ? i.e. `constructor(props){ super(props); this.state = { value: ''} }`

Comment: @Seba99 still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer and Edge are caching the input tag. On Windows, hit the Ctrl+F5 shortcut to hard refresh. But for me I hit Ctrl+double hit F5 in Edge then it refreshes. You can also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737602/select-control-created-in-react-does-not-reset-on-browser-refresh-ie11-and-edge).